# How is data stored in a bit vector?

Tags: data-structures, language-agnostic, bitvector

I'm a bit confused how a fixed size bit vector stores its data.
Let's assume that we have a bit vector `bv` that I want to store `hello` in as ASCII.

So we do `bv[0]=104`, `bv[1]=101`, `bv[2]=108`, `bv[3]=108`, `bv[4]=111`.

How is the ASCII of `hello` represented in the bit vector?

Is it as binary like this: `[01101000][01100101][01101100][01101100][01101111]`
or as ASCII like this: `[104][101][108][108][111]`

The following paper [HAMPI](http://people.csail.mit.edu/akiezun/issta54-kiezun.pdf) at section 3.5 step 2, the author is assigning ascii code to a bit vector, but Im confused how the char is represented in the bit vector.

Comment: I believe it depends upon the language how it is internally represented.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should probably read up on [what a bit vector is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_vector), just to make sure we're on the same page.

Bit vectors don't represent ASCII characters, they represent **bits**. Trying to do `bv[0]=104` on a bit vector will probably not compile / run, or, if it does, it's **very** unlikely to do what you expect.

The operations that you would expect to be supported is along the lines of `set the 5th bit to 1`, `set the 10th bit to 0`, `set all these bit to this`, `OR the bits of these two vectors` and probably some others.

How these are actually stored in memory is completely up to the programming language, and, on top of that, it may even be completely up to a given implementation of that language.

The *general* consensus (not a rule) is that each bit should take up roughly 1 bit in memory (maybe, on average, slightly more, since there could be overhead related to storing these).

As one example (how Java does it), you could have an array of 64-bit numbers and store 64 bits in each position. The translation to ASCII won't make sense in this case.

**Another thing you should know** - even ASCII gets stored as bits in memory, so those 2 arrays are essentially the same, unless you meant something else.

Comment: Ok. Let's forget about bv[x]= some ASCII. Can you use bit vectors to store hello? or any data type and how is that represented theoretically not in memory? I read somewhere that bit vectors are used to represent different data types such as strings, integers etc. but dont know how that is possible. Im still confused

Comment: If you take a look at this paper at section 3.5 and read step 2 http://people.csail.mit.edu/akiezun/issta54-kiezun.pdf . They are using bit vectors to store ascii chars in it.

Comment: @msr I honestly can't see how what that paper describes is different from a character array (not that I have enough time to read through the whole thing thoroughly to understand exactly right now), so it's array of size 6 with each element being 1 byte / 8 bits in size, each representing 1 ASCII character. I think that paper is essential to understanding the question, if you want a better, more specific answer, you may want to put that in your question (preferably copy the entire step 2 into the question rather than just linking to it).

Comment: Thats how im understanding it as well. but since bit vectors consists of 0 and 1 so I thought that each char is represented as a binary at each bucket of the bit vector. anyways thank you for the help.:)